# Why is not returning if the checkbutton is ticked?

Tags: python, tkinter

Im trying to return if a checkbutton is marked but it does not work. It always prints a 0 even when its marked that it should print a 1.

```
var7_u = IntVar()
self.var7_u=var7_u
var7_s = IntVar()
self.var7_s=var7_s
year7_label = Label(root,text="Y7").grid(row=5)
self.year7_upper_check = Checkbutton(root,variable=var7_u)
self.year7_upper_check.grid(row=5,column=1)
year7_standard_check = Checkbutton(root,variable=var7_s).grid(row=5,column=3)
submit_but = Button(root,text="Submit",command=lambda[self.insert(self.var7_s,self.var7_u)])

 def insert(self,var7_u,var7_s):
        variable=var7_u.get()
        print(variable)
```

Comment: did you run it in terminal/console/cmd.exe to see errors messages ? I see one mistake which should display error.

Comment: text `"does not work."` is useless information - you have to describe it becuse we can't run code and we can't read in your mind. If you get error message then put it in question. always put full error message (Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: it always prints a 0 even though it is marked and it should print a 1 when its marked.

Comment: i don't know why you have `var7_s` and `self.var7_s` - you could use only one. And if you have only one button then you could use `self.var7_s` directly in `insert` without sending it as argument. You also change order in execution `self.insert(..._s, ..._u)` but in definiton `insert(self, ..._u, ..._s)` - so maybe you check wrong Checkbutton. Maybe you marked first `Checkbutton` but in `insert` you get value from second `Checkbutton`.

Comment: if i do not do var7_s and self.var7_s  it says that var7_s is not declared and changing the order did not work.